# not sure what is the error, I try to call different libraries but it is telling me its not correct

Tags: python

```py
import random as r 

def gen_random(low, high):
  generated = r.random * (high - low) + low
  generated = int(generated)
  return generated
```

I have try randint, but for me it looks good

Comment: What the error? If it tells you it's not correct, thats the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, you did not put the paranthesis `()` after the r.random function, your code should look like this now

```
import random as r


def gen_random(low, high):
    generated = r.random() * (high - low) + low
    generated = int(generated)
    return generated
```

Comment: thank you for the help, it was silly mistake, but it was getting on my head

Comment: yeah no problem